# Dependency injection with .NET Core and abstract (base) class

Tags: c#, inheritance, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have 1 abstract class that is used by 2 other classes inheriting from it:

```
public abstract class FiltererBase
{
    ColorsOrderer colorsOrderer;

    public FiltererBase(ColorsOrderer colorsOrderer)
    {
        this.colorsOrderer = colorsOrderer;
    }

    protected string OrderColors(string colors)
    {
        return string.Join("", colors.ToCharArray().OrderBy(i => colorsOrderer.Order[i]));
    }
}


public class Filterer1 : FiltererBase
{
    public Filterer1(ColorsOrderer colorsOrderer)
        : base(colorsOrderer) { }
}

public class Filterer2 : FiltererBase
{
    public Filterer2(ColorsOrderer colorsOrderer)
        : base(colorsOrderer) { }
}
```

As you can see, I am using dependency injection (DI) and passing the class instantiated from the child constructor to the parent constructor.

Is it really the best way to do DI with abstract (base) classes? Isn't the .NET Core framework providing a more automatic way to do that?

Comment: Looks completely fine and as it should be. You can not inject into abstract class directly as abstract class can not be instantiated itself.

Comment: @Roman.Pavelko ok, I was looking for a less manual way to do that, in the case where I will have multiple abstract classes that will have dozens of dependencies like that...

Comment: There are too many cases where the framework would not know what to do. For example your derived class accepts 2 `ColorsOrderer` parameters but the abstract class only accepts one - which one should the framework pass down? What if the abstract class has multiple constructors one that takes one parameter and another that takes 2. Which one should the framework call? There are too many cases that the compiler/framework would need to handle so it is kept simple and you need to call the base constructor yourself

Comment: @ibiza What are you ***actually*** trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to inject parameters into a parent constructor.

You could use a [composition approach instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Refactoring your code to a composition approach, it would appear like this:

```
public class ColorFilter
{
    ColorsOrderer colorsOrderer;

    public ColorFilter(ColorsOrderer colorsOrderer)
    {
        this.colorsOrderer = colorsOrderer;
    }

    public string OrderColors(string colors)
    {
        return string.Join("", colors.ToCharArray().OrderBy(i => colorsOrderer.Order[i]));
    }
}


public class Filterer1
{
    ColorFilter colorFilter;

    public Filterer1(ColorFilter colorFilter)
    {
        this.colorFilter = colorFilter;
    }

    public string OrderColors(string colors)
    {
        return this.colorFilter(colors);
    }
}

public class Filterer2
{
    ColorFilter colorFilter;

    public Filterer2(ColorFilter colorFilter)
    {
        this.colorFilter = colorFilter;
    }

    public string OrderColors(string colors)
    {
        return this.colorFilter(colors);
    }
}
```